# Total amount not populating for online form

Tags: civicontribute, joomla, contribution-page

I am building out my first front end form and the total amount field is not populating. We are running on Joomla 3.8.12 and CiviCRM 5.5.1.

http://dev.victoryliving.org/index.php/donate

Please help, thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, it looks like you're not using a price set - so it's actually a mystery why "Total Amount" appears in the first place.  You don't have anything to total!  I just confirmed on a test site that I don't normally see "Total Amount" on a contribution page that doesn't require it.

If you could edit your question to display a screenshot of the price configuration for this contribution page, perhaps someone will notice something amiss.

Comment: I added a photo. I had a price set I tried to test, but deleted it and unchecked the box for it when I realized it wasn't what I needed. So not sure why that did not go away.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot and details!  It sounds like there might be a bug that exists when you enable, then disable the price set.  Do you have a way to run SQL?  Could you update the query `SELECT is_quick_config FROM civicrm_contribution_page ccp JOIN civicrm_price_set_entity cpse ON ccp.id = cpse.entity_id AND entity_table = 'civicrm_contribution_page' JOIN civicrm_price_set cps ON cpse.price_set_id = cps.id WHERE ccp.id = x` where that final "x" is the id of the contribution page in question? The id is "1" if it's your first contribution page.

Comment: I tried running it however the result shows: Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0007 seconds.) and it does not appear to have made a difference

Comment: That command wouldn't have changed anything - it's just a diagnostic.  And I don't think it's possible to have zero rows there.  Maybe the contribution page ID is off? To explain further - there's a record in `civicrm_price_set` that corresponds to your price options (even if you're NOT using price sets).  The `is_quick_config` will be set to `1` for a "real" price set, and "0" if you're using the "Fixed Contribution Options".  I'm wondering if somehow your price set has a `1` where it should be a `0`.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Hmm, maybe the system still sees 1 even thought I deleted the one I made and unchecked the box? And the contribution id is correct. Only ever made the 1 page and the id is 1. I may just have to remake the page and see if that fixes it